# async socket client once connected to a third-party software continue listening for incoming messages

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a WPF application that once sent a message via TCP to a third-party application, listen for the answer and continue listening to incoming communication (This third-party application sends feedback to the most recently connected or authenticated controller) until another message has to be sent and so on.

It has to be async because my application must run continuously being able to perform other actions.
Basically I've adapted this (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) example to WPF using a backgoundWorker and never closing the socket.

The problem seems to be that

`client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0, 
    new asyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);`

Won't loopback if the last bytes read is less than the buffer size.

my code is:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace socket_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly BackgroundWorker BWI;
        public AsyncSocketReceiver ASR;
        public string risposta = "";
        public string rispostaOLD;
        public bool newMessage = false;
        public string Extmessage;
        public int Mcounter = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BWI = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
            BWI.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BWI_DoWork);
            BWI.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BWI_RunWorkerCompleted);
            BWI.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BWI_ProgressChangedEventHandler);
        }

        private void BWI_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = -1;
            BackgroundWorker myBW = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            ASR = new AsyncSocketReceiver("192.168.1.106", 3040);
            ASR.Connect();
            ASR.Send(string.Format("[{0}] ping \r", Mcounter));
            ASR.sendDone.WaitOne();
            newMessage = false;
            while (AsyncSocketReceiver.client.Connected)
            {
                if (newMessage)
                {
                    var toSend = string.Format("[{0}] " + Extmessage + "\r", Mcounter++);
                    ASR.Send(toSend);
                    ASR.sendDone.WaitOne();
                    newMessage = false;
                }
                ASR.Receive();
                ASR.receiveDone.WaitOne();
                risposta = ASR.response;

                myBW.ReportProgress(i++);
            }
        }

        private void BWI_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            BWI.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void BWI_ProgressChangedEventHandler(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CueAnswer.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            CueAnswer.AppendText(risposta);
        }

        private void AsyncSocket_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => BWI.RunWorkerAsync();

        private void AskC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ASR.receiveDone.Set();
            Extmessage = MessageToSend.Text;
            newMessage = true;
        }
    }

    public class AsyncSocketReceiver
    {
        private static IPEndPoint remoteEP;
        public static Socket client;
        public ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public String response;
        public String query;

        public AsyncSocketReceiver(String myIp, int myPort)
        {
            remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIp), myPort);
            client = new Socket(IPAddress.Parse(myIp).AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
            {
                Blocking = false
            };
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
        }

        private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Send(String data)
        {
            query = data;
            response = "";
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Receive()
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = new StateObject
                {
                    workSocket = client
                };
                receiveDone.Reset();
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0,
                                 new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post a part of your code ?

Comment: I've added the code...